# Incomplete information about deadlock in Thread Stack Trace?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, deadlock, stack-trace

Recently on the server of my project we encountered a deadlock condition and on checking the thread stack trace we could't find much information. Here is the stack trace:

## Found one Java-level deadlock:

```
"pool-1-thread-70":
  waiting to lock Monitor@0x00007f60d40a0760 (Object@0x00000000b9c02a00, a com/hal/real/Real),
  which is held by "pool-17-thread-81"

"pool-17-thread-81":
  waiting to lock Monitor@0x00007f60d410b4e0 (Object@0x00000000b9c03980, a java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap),
  which is held by "pool-1-thread-70"

Found a total of 1 deadlock.

Thread 23794: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=226 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack$SNode, boolean, long) @bci=174, line=453 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(java.lang.Object, boolean, long) @bci=102, line=352 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=11, line=903 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=141, line=1043 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=17, line=1103 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=603 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=679 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 23792: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=226 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack$SNode, boolean, long) @bci=174, line=453 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(java.lang.Object, boolean, long) @bci=102, line=352 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=11, line=903 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=141, line=1043 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=17, line=1103 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=603 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=679 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 23757: (state = BLOCKED)
 - com.hal.real.RealUser.getRegularSnapshot() @bci=15, line=646 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.hal.real.RealUser.getRealSnapshot() @bci=10, line=671 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.hal.real.RealUser.getRealUsers() @bci=9, line=618 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.hal.real.Real.getAvat() @bci=4, line=1146 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.hal.real.RealManager.getWebServers(com.hal.real.Real, java.util.List) @bci=184, line=220 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.hal.message.core.StreamUriReq.exec() @bci=398, line=108 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.hal.real.RealClientHandler.msgReceived(org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession, java.lang.Object) @bci=91, line=83 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilter$NextFilter, org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession, java.lang.Object) @bci=51, line=690 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterChain$Entry, org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession, java.lang.Object) @bci=22, line=417 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain, org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterChain$Entry, org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession, java.lang.Object) @bci=4, line=47 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession, java.lang.Object) @bci=18, line=765 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire() @bci=110, line=74 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run() @bci=1, line=63 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=46, line=1110 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=603 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=679 (Interpreted frame)
```

Any Way to tackle this problem. Clearly pool-1-thread-70 and pool-17-thread-81 are the threads responsible for deadlock but no information about which function were they accessing when this deadlock occurred and which synchronized map the thread has locked

Comment: Please could you format your post to make it more readable?

Comment: Hi NPE,
I have formatted the post